# Behaviour of loop.create_task

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am new to asyncio library and wrote the following code to understand its behaviour

```
CONNECTIONS = 3
REPEAT = 5

async def test(payload):
    for i in range(REPEAT):
        print(payload)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def run_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(CONNECTIONS):
        loop.create_task(test(f"Hello World {i}"))

asyncio.run(run_test())
```

However, when I run it, I got the following output

```
Hello World 0
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
```

I was expecting each of them to be printed 5 times. Can somebody help me understand it? Besides, what should I change to observe these statements printed 5 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created the tasks but you have not launched it, also, you should wait for them to finish, otherwise the eventloop will end early. To launch several tasks at the same time you must use `asyncio.gather()`:

```
async def run_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = []
    for i in range(CONNECTIONS):
        task = loop.create_task(test(f"Hello World {i}"))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```